# How can I get all my friends profiles in a single request with the Facebook PHP SDK 3.0?

Tags: php, facebook, sdk

I'm trying to retrieve all my friends, specifically I want to get each friends location information (hometown_location and location) for the purpose of putting them on a map. I've tried the following code, which throws an error: Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: ids=8689768,86576659,898676 (etc)

```
 $friends = $facebook->api("/$user/friends");

 foreach($friends['data'] as $key => $friend) {

$friend_list .= ($key!=0) ? "," : "";
$friend_list .= $friend['id'];
 }

 $friend_profiles = $facebook->api("/ids=$friend_list");
```

Any ideas on how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about FQL query: SELECT uid, name, hometown_location, current_location FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me())

Returns also null values but no exception, there must also be a way to filtering null values via the FQL query

Try it here:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

With the URL: https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT uid, name, hometown_location, current_location FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me())

Comment: [This Link](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=fql%3Fq%3DSELECT%20uid%2C%20name%2C%20hometown_location%2C%20current_location%20FROM%20user%20WHERE%20uid%20IN%20(SELECT%20uid2%20FROM%20friend%20WHERE%20uid1%3Dme())) should do it, if not, grab a new access token and make sure you have permission to access that data

Comment: That works really well, thanks! I kept seeing notices about FQL being depreciated or some such so I was avoiding it, but that's exactly the return I want so hopefully it remains working.